# Confused: In Chrome Dev-Tools Lighthouse says to be blocking requests which the network tab doesn't show as blocked

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

I am using Lighthouse on Chrome 87 devTools. While evaluating my page, it seems to be freezing completely for several seconds. Often it tells me that my page loaded too slowly and so results may be incomplete. What I find strange is that in the console output I find lots and lots of messages saying "Request blocked by DevTools: "<URL>", about a hundred of them. However, when I look in the network tab, there are NO blocked requests at all. And the resources Lighthouse says it blocked are in fact there, I can see them.

I have also used the Request Blocking feature (it was so well hidden away I can't find it again) to make sure request blocking was OFF.

I have seen another SO post where somebody said he had the same problem, but restarting DevTools made it go away. In my case it never goes away. Has anybody any information to help me?

Comment: maybe there is also a filter applied to the network list ? You can select the "Request Blocking" tab in the small "hamburger menu" on the LEFT side of the devtools window (you might be used to find these menus on the right side)

Comment: @kca thanks, I found it again...! ...hidden away under "more tools". As to the network list, if there is a filter I didn't define it.